# simpleweather js weather icons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to make a weather app using simpleweather js. I've successfully been able to get the app to show the weather for my current location but i'm not sure how to get weather icons to show next to the temperature. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/perrylivingston/pen/dMLLOP
These are the icons i'm trying to use:https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons

***html:***

```
    <div id="the_weather"></div>
    <button class="js-geolocation"> Use Location</button>
    <i class="wi wi-yahoo-31"></i>
```

***css:***

```
body {
background-image: url("http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/blue-sky.jpg");
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#the_weather {
width: 500px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

@font-face {
src: url('weathericons-regular-webfont.eot') format ('embedded-opentype');
src: url('weathericons-regular-webfont.svg') format ('svg');
src: url('weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
src: url('weathericons-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
src: url('weathericons-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
}

i {
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 160px;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

#the_weather li {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
}

.icon-0:before { content: ":"; }
.icon-1:before { content: "p"; }
.icon-2:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-3:before { content: "Q"; }
.icon-4:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-5:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-6:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-7:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-8:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-9:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-10:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-11:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-12:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-13:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-14:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-15:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-16:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-17:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-18:before { content: "U"; }
.icon-19:before { content: "Z"; }
.icon-20:before { content: "Z"; }
.icon-21:before { content: "Z"; }
.icon-22:before { content: "Z"; }
.icon-23:before { content: "Z"; }
.icon-24:before { content: "E"; }
.icon-25:before { content: "E"; }
.icon-26:before { content: "3"; }
.icon-27:before { content: "a"; }
.icon-28:before { content: "A"; }
.icon-29:before { content: "a"; }
.icon-30:before { content: "A"; }
.icon-31:before { content: "6"; }
.icon-32:before { content: "1"; }
.icon-33:before { content: "6"; }
.icon-34:before { content: "1"; }
.icon-35:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-36:before { content: "1"; }
.icon-37:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-38:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-39:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-40:before { content: "M"; }
.icon-41:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-42:before { content: "I"; }
.icon-43:before { content: "W"; }
.icon-44:before { content: "a"; }
.icon-45:before { content: "S"; }
.icon-46:before { content: "U"; }
.icon-47:before { content: "S"; }

#weather h2 {
margin: 0 0 8px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 100px;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

#weather ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#weather li {
background: #fff;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.90);
padding: 20px;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 5px;
```

}

```
#weather .currently {
margin: 0 20px;
}

button {
display: block;
margin: 15px auto;
width: 140px;
padding: 5px;
background:#efcc3a;
color: #0;
font-weight: bold;
border: 0;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

jquery
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    $('.js-geolocation').show(); 
    } else {
    $('.js-geolocation').hide();
    }

```
$('.js-geolocation').on('click', function() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
loadWeather(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude);
});
});


$(document).ready(function() {
loadWeather('New York','');
});

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
$.simpleWeather({
location: location,
woeid: woeid,
unit: 'f',
success: function(weather) {
html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i>          '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
html += '<li>'+weather.alt.temp+'&deg;C</li></ul>';  

$("#the_weather").html(html);
},
error: function(error) {
$("#the_weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
}
});
}
```

Comment: According to the icon's compatibility page (https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/api-list.html), the equivalent for `wi-yahoo-31` is `night-clear` so instead of `<i class="wi wi-yahoo-31"></i>` you would use `<i class="wi wi-night-clear"></i>` - so instead of adding `weather.code` to the icon, you would need to have a look-up table (mapping yahoo's icons with the weather icons) and use the replacement every time.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I think so. But as the code stands now I'm only getting the letter placeholder in the CSS. How do I fix this to first get the yahoo icons to appear before mapping it to the new icons? I had previously done <i class="wi wi-night-clear"></i> in the html with no success. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: in the code pen, are you including the weather icon's css? (when I modify you pen, I can see the night clear icon (lower left, not centered)

Comment: never mind creating your own mapping, the library has them mapped for you already.  See running example in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working correctly.
Make sure you insert your libraries in the order below

1. JQuery
2. Simple Weather

and don't forget to include your weather icons CSS and Bootstrap CSS files

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    $('.js-geolocation').show();
  } else {
    $('.js-geolocation').hide();
  }

  // button handler
  $('.js-geolocation').on('click', function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      loadWeather(position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
    });
  });
  

  // loads weather
  function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
    $.simpleWeather({
      location: location,
      woeid: woeid,
      unit: 'f',
      success: function(weather) {
        
        html = '<h2><i class="wi wi-yahoo-' + weather.code + '"></i> ' + weather.temp + '&deg;' + weather.units.temp + '</h2>';
        html += '<ul><li>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</li>';
        html += '<li class="currently">' + weather.currently + '</li>';
        html += '<li>' + weather.alt.temp + '&deg;C</li></ul>';

        $("#the_weather").html(html);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        $("#the_weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
      }
    });
  }


  // init
  loadWeather('Miami', '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.10/css/weather-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="the_weather"></div>
<button class="js-geolocation">Use Location</button>

<i class="wi wi-night-clear"></i>
```